# How to strip "eq." from cleveref?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

How can I make cleveref output `(1)` instead of `eq. (1)` when referencing equations only?

Comment: Just use `\eqref` (needs `amsmath`).

Comment: Um..., I might want to change my style later, isn't that what cleveref is meant for? Just want to be consistent. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `\crefformat` (notice that the same formatting can be achieved simply using `\eqref` from `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{equation}{(#2#1#3)}

\begin{document}
\ref{eq:test}\eqref{eq:test}\cref{eq:test}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:test}
a=b.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might also want to use a similar formatting for a range:

```
\crefrangeformat{equation}{(#3#1#4) to~(#5#2#6)}
```

and for multiple references, with the "and" between them (e.g. `(1), (2) and (3)`).:

```
\crefmultiformat{equation}{(#2#1#3)}%
{ and~(#2#1#3)}{, (#2#1#3)}{ and~(#2#1#3)}
```

*NOTE:* In `crefmultiformat` spaces are important.

Both examples were taken from [official doc](http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex/cleveref.pdf), and `eq` part simply removed.

Comment: Ah, great tip on range format. I missed that one. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Added `crefmultiformat` to your answer, hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: @drozzy by no means :-) Thanks for the valuable addition.

Answer (score 24):

Even simpler, just put

```
\crefname{equation}{}{}
```

in your preamble. Then all the formats get defined for you automatically. (No need to redefine all of `\crefformat`, `\crefmultiformat`, `\crefrangeformat`, `\labelcrefformat`!)

These days, `cleveref` is...clever enough to omit the usual non-breaking space after the cross-reference name if you define an empty name.

Answer (score 3):

In case one wants to do this only locally, and not for the whole document, use `\labelcref{…}` instead of `\cref{…}`.

(This is the same as using `\ref{…}`, except it can also benefit from cleveref's multi-reference functionality).

Comment: Thanks for this! This is exactly what I was looking for.